# HTML page taking too much time to load and page is becoming irresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

My web page is taking too much time to load.
reason is that page have a HTML table which has around 3000 columns and every column has a text box within it.
Is there a way so that I can reduce the loading time or suggest if there is any other alternative.

thanks in advance

EDIT - Ok let me tell you the exact senerio, my table needs to show the date wise data and the Date (like 14-Dec-2012) will be the column header itself. the latest date will be the first column, then the past dates will comes across, some thing like (14-Dec-2012|13-Dec-2012|12-Dec-2012.....) every day when system date changes a new column would be added as the first column. There are around 200 rows.
Its an JSP page and in a for loop I am creating the table header first, then in second for loop creating the table cells containing the values in textbox (so that user can edit them anytime).

code sample - 
Header -

```
<%
    Date today = new Date();
    String col = "";
    today = RDUtils.addDays(today, 1);
for(int i=0;i<=columnCount;i++){
    today = RDUtils.addDays(today, -1);
    col = RDUtils.getStringDateCol(today);
%>
<th class="TableHeader"><div><%=col%></div></th>
<%} %>
```

Table cells -

```
for(int j=0;j<=columnCount;j++){%>
    <input maxlength="5" onblur="fillZero(this);" onFocus='clearField(this);' onkeypress="if (checkEnter())return false;" onkeyup='if (checkEnter()) move("<%=i %>");' size="5" type="text" name="txtEntry<%=de.getId()%>" value="<%=val%>" id="<%=de.getId()%>"/></div> </td>
```

JS functions -

```
function checkEnter(e){
    characterCode = e.keyCode;
    return characterCode == 13;
}
function fillZero(obj){
if(obj.value==''){
    obj.value = 0;
}
 }
 function clearField(obj){
var perfix = obj.name.substring(8, obj.name.length);
var chkObj = document.getElementById('deCheck'+perfix);
if(!chkObj.checked)chkObj.checked=true;
if(obj.value==0){
    obj.value = '';
}
 }
```

Comment: Can you supply a link or a fiddle?

Comment: You have some javascript around that page, don't you?

Comment: you can do one thing like load some columns once than load by ajax but there is the cost that it will increase the load on server

Comment: 3000 columns or rows? Anyway, I think you probably want to redesign the page, maybe adding a search and/or pagination? Even if the page loads responsively, it's hard for users to process the information.

Comment: If it is a server-side generated page, you try "flushing" the content at specific intervals.  However, that's not guaranteed.  I'm more inclined to go the AJAX route BUT returning JSON data and letting the client's computer render it.  This you could setup an intervals as well to get content loading quickly.

Comment: @Bergi No javascript as such.

Comment: @vermap: Then what do those event handlers refer to, e.g. `fillZero`, `clearField`, `checkEnter`? If you think the JS is irrelevant to the question, please remove the tag, else please add the relevant code.

Comment: @Bergi I said that because no javascript code is being executed at the time of table creation. I think so!! correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @vermap What is the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

#### It is better to use pagination using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

And use the AJAX method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../ajax/sources/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen but pagination is not going to help me, as the problem is there with the no. of columns (around 3000) not the no. of rows.

Comment: Oh columns. What kind of an application is this?

Comment: Application is for to manage the the data for Regular deposit (RD) where client need to see the data from the begining of the a/c date say Dec 2002 to current date i.e. Dec 2012 (see the above code for ref.) on daily basis to in this case there would be around 10yr*12mon*30d = 3600 column

Comment: Omg! But my suggestion would be, leave this Datatables. But good idea to load the columns through an AJAX request.

Comment: but you can not load columns in parts within a table, if so how?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into above mentioned problem??

Comment: Tried my level best buddy. :(